# Make method available in capistrano deployfile

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have my own gem that streamlines deployment for me, as the servers have the some configuration.

The structure is as following:

```
- .
- ..
- lib
  - capistrano
    - foo
      - common.rb
    - foo.rb
```

foo.rb:

```
require "capistrano"
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
require "capistrano/foo/common"
```

common.rb:

```
def _cset(name, *args, &block)
  unless exists?(name)
    set(name, *args, &block)
  end
end

def _baz(param)
end
```

I can't seem to call  `_baz` in my deploy files, while I am able to call `_cset` just fine. How can I make `_baz` callable in my deploy files?

Exception:

> capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:122:in `method_missing_with_variables': undefined method `_symlink' for # (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a `require` problem, `capistrano/foo` wasn't properly required in the project itself and I don't require `capistrano/foo/common` explicitly in my base recipes.